# Is there any better way to write this Python code?

Tags: python

I am learning to write Object-Oriented Programming in Python and practised the following code. Not sure but I feel that I am writing repetitive code in the inheritance section. Would it be possible to write this code in a better way?

```
class Dog():
    species = "Canis familiaris"

    #defining object attributes
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"

#INHERITENCE - creating child classes for Breeds
class jackrusselterrier(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Arf"):
        return f"{self.name} says {sound}"

class Dachshund(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Woof"):
        return f"{self.name} says {sound}"

class BullDog(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Grr"):
        return f"{self.name} says {sound}"

#instantiation of object
miles = jackrusselterrier("miles",4)
buddy = Dachshund("buddy",9)
jack = BullDog("Jack",3)
jim = BullDog("Jim",5)

#displaying result
print(miles)
print(miles.speak())
print(type(miles))
print(isinstance(miles,BullDog))
```

Comment: This question is better suited for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. SO is for requesting assistance with specific issues in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Better" is a qualitative term, but if you want to repeat less code, there are several ways you could leverage inheritance further to do so (to some extent).

One idea is to make the `speak()` method in each child class call a shared method from the parent class, `_speak()`. This has the advantage of better representing that all three child objects have similar underlying behavior.

```
class Dog():
    species = "Canis familiaris"

    #defining object attributes
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"
    
    def _speak(self,sound):
        return f"{self.name} says {sound}"

#INHERITENCE - creating child classes for Breeds
class jackrusselterrier(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Arf"):
        return self._speak(sound)

class Dachshund(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Woof"):
        return self._speak(sound)

class BullDog(Dog):
    def speak(self,sound="Grr"):
        return self._speak(sound)

#instantiation of object
miles = jackrusselterrier("miles",4)
buddy = Dachshund("buddy",9)
jack = BullDog("Jack",3)
jim = BullDog("Jim",5)

#displaying result
print(miles)
print(miles.speak())
print(type(miles))
print(isinstance(miles,BullDog))
print(buddy.speak())
print(jack.speak())
print(jim.speak())
```

But each child class still has a method that does pretty much the same thing (calling the parent class), and only differ on their default sound. We could instead only have one `speak` method, and make this default sound for each class a variable we create when we create the child class. Note however this adds some complexity, as if we make a `__init__()` method for the child class, we have to call the parent's `__init__()` method too, and that is a little messy in python.

```
class Dog():
    species = "Canis familiaris"

    #defining object attributes
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"
    
    def speak(self,sound=None):
        if sound is None:
            sound = self.default_sound
        return f"{self.name} says {sound}"

#INHERITENCE - creating child classes for Breeds
class jackrusselterrier(Dog):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.default_sound = "Arf"
        super(jackrusselterrier,self).__init__(name,age)

class Dachshund(Dog):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.default_sound = "Woof"
        super(Dachshund,self).__init__(name,age)

class BullDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.default_sound = "Grr"
        super(BullDog,self).__init__(name,age)

#instantiation of object
miles = jackrusselterrier("miles",4)
buddy = Dachshund("buddy",9)
jack = BullDog("Jack",3)
jim = BullDog("Jim",5)

#displaying result
print(miles)
print(miles.speak())
print(type(miles))
print(isinstance(miles,BullDog))
print(buddy.speak())
print(jack.speak())
print(jim.speak())
```

Both these options aren't much less repetitive, but they both have the advantage of communicating in different ways that each child class inherits it's speaking behavior from the parent. Which way you do it I think would come down to your preferred style.